# Facebook login error with https

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication

I got this error message when login with facebook.

100 Message: Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Redirect url with http working fine but with https I'm getting above error message.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your redirect url to include https.

For example https://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

I believed you have used different **redirect_uri** in your facebook app settings and Oauth API code. thats why you got this error.

For facebook login you must set same **redirect_uri** into both place.